# how to show the overall summary in a forest plot exponantiated?

Tags: r, metafor

I am running a meta analysis in R where the summary measures are given in logHR. The data are given below

```
logHR<-c(-0.2877,-0.2357,-0.2877,-0.3455)
   seHR<-c(0.0639,0.07834,0.09768,0.05673)
   df<-data.frame(logHR,seHR)
   meta<-metagen(df$logHR,df$seHR)
   forest(meta)
```

my questions is how can I make the forest plot to show the results with the confidence intervals as HR and not logHR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the summary measure to Hazard Ratio. Just include the parameter `sm = "HR"` when creating your `meta` object.

```r
library(meta)

meta <- metagen(df$logHR, df$seHR, sm = 'HR')
forest(meta)
```

[image]